# Почему map не печатает список

Tags: python, python-3.x, список

Вот мой код:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
map(lambda x: print(x), l)
```

Почему он не выводит список?

Answer (score 13):

`map` - ленивый объект, `print` применяется к очередному элементу `l` только когда очередной элемент будет запрошен у самого `map`.
Форсировать вычисления можно, например, обернув `map` в `list`

```py
list(map(lambda x: print(x), l))
```

или каким нибудь другим образом заставить `map` вернуть все элементы

```py
'что-то, чего точно нет в результирующей коллекции' in map(lambda x: print(x), l)
```

```py
for _ in map(lambda x: print(x), l):
    pass
```

Но все же лучше применять `map` только тогда, когда результат важен. В вашем случае важен только побочный эффект - вывод на экран. Обычный `for` в этой ситуации будет гораздо более уместным.

Answer (score 5):

Потому что [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) возвращает итератор а не готовый список. Это может быть очень полезным когда вам надо обрабатывать огромные массивы данных.

Попробуйте так:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, l))
print(squares)
# [1, 4, 9, 16]
```

Answer (score 5):

Потому что он [ленивый](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Результат надо *вычислить*

```
list(map(lambda x: print(x), l))
```

Answer (score 4):

Уже имеющиеся ответы достаточно полно раскрывают вопрос, я лишь хочу немного их дополнить:

1. В вашем случае `lambda` не обязательна, в `map` можно передать функцию `print` напрямую: `map(print, l)`.
2. Если хочется напечатать список, можно просто использовать функцию `print` один раз:

   ```
   print(*l)            # распечатает список в одну строку, разделяя элементы пробелами
   print(*l, sep='\n')  # распечатает список, по одному элементу на строке
   ```

   Синтаксис `*l` называется распаковкой ([unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)) аргументов.